# httperrors in asp.net web.config file

Tags: asp.net

I am using the httperror in order to redirect user to the custom 404 page when a non existent resource or page is requested by the user with the following code;

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error.aspx"   responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

which is working fine, but I am curious that if somebody can explain it to me, what is the meaning of remove statuscode and error statuscode tags than it would be helpful for me. Is it something like remove tag will remove the statuscode 404, if this is the case then what status code will it return, is it 404 or something else, any help would be highly appreciated.